# Disabling callbacks in data migration with ActiveRecord - Ruby/Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, activerecord, callback

I am importing CSV files in my database through a function which looks like this:

```
def import_csv_into_db
        CSV.foreach(Rails.root.join('db', 'csv_export',filename), headers: true) do |row|
          class_name = filename_renamed.constantize
          next if row.to_hash['deleted_at'] != nil
          Customer.before_create.reject! {|callback| callback.method.to_s == 'unique' }
          Customer.create!(row.to_hash)
        end
      end
```

The current file which I am testing is the customers.csv.

> I would like to skip methods or better said, the callbacks which are
> triggered when I create objects to insert data into the corresponding db, e.g. `Customer.create!(row.to_hash)`

This is why I tried to implement the following method:

```
Customer.before_create.reject! {|callback| callback.method.to_s == 'unique' }
```

so that I can skip callbacks from the `customer.rb` model

But I get the error:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments calling `method` (0 for 1)
```

I understand the error, but what I don't understand is how to correctly implement the `Customer.before_create` line mentioned above.

My method is implemented in the `seeds.rb` and is triggered upon running `rake db:seed` and yes it works fine withother CSV's, just the ones with ***callbacks*** are causing trouble.

I found the .before_create.reject method [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20120701221754/http://blog.viarails.net/2009/1/29/disabling-callbacks-in-an-activerecord-data-migration)

Comment: Do you want to silence all callbacks or just a specific one?

Comment: @the_spectator typically all of them, or could you maybe show how to do both?

Answer (score 1):

The error comes from the fact that `callback` (in your block) is an object, and its `method` method returns a method given the name. That is: `'a string'.method(:upcase)` and `SomeClass.method(:new)`.

You can use `insert!` instead of `create!`, which skips everything, but then you have to add all the needed columns (including timestamps):

```rb
attributes = row.to_hash
attributes['created_at'] = attributes['updated_at'] = DateTime.now.utc
class_name.insert!(attributes)
```